# ODBC single connection or one per thread

Tags: c, odbc, mutex

I wanted to know which approach is better, to have a single odbc connection shared among a series o threads, using a mutex to make sure that there are no concurrence problems, or to have one per thread and not use mutex. I don't see any substantial advantage in any of them, but maybe there are things in the odbc implementation i'm missing.

I tried to look for similar questions but couldn't find anything, sorry if it's been answered before

Answer (score 0):

The ODBC Driver Manager already provides Connection Pooling: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms716319(v=vs.85).aspx

> Connection pooling enables an application to use a connection from a
>   pool of connections that do not need to be reestablished for each use.

In short: If a Connection is released by your application, and connection pooling is enabled, the driver manager will maybe not close the connection immediately, but keep it for some time open. If your application requests a new connection to be opened, the driver manager might return such an already open connection from its pool.

So: I would not care about do all the locking within your threads, but just enable connection pooling and let each driver use its own connection.

Note that you can either enable connection pooling on a process level or for each environment handle - see the remarks in the documentation:

> Enables connection pooling by calling SQLSetEnvAttr to set the
>   SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_POOLING environment attribute to
>   SQL_CP_ONE_PER_DRIVER or SQL_CP_ONE_PER_HENV.

Answer (score -1):

I think that it depends on what you want to achieve with your implementation. Having only one shared connection with a lot of threads will result in threads being blocked and waiting for the connection to be available. This can decrease the performance. If you have a large number of threads, I'd rather create a sort of connection pool that handles the creation, usage and closure of connections.

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment.